# How to add "-lsqlite3" option into makefile of an open source programe

Tags: linux, sqlite

I want to test a function into an open source program, such as LLDPD, it will get input data from SQLite3 database, then output it. But there is always a problem that "undefined function sqlite3_open" when using "make" after "./configure".

I think this problem happens because I can't using "-lsqlite3" option when using "make" to compile lldp.c file - the file I modified.

I want to add "-lsqlite3" into the makefile to solve my problem, but I don't know it's legal or not?

If it's legal, could you give me some advice to do that? I really appreciate that.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add link flags by setting `LDFLAGS`:

```
LDFLAGS="-lsqlite3" ./configure
```